# how to load twitter data from hdfs using pig?

Tags: hadoop, twitter, apache-pig

I just streaming some twitter data using flume and cluster it into HDFS now I try to load it into pig for analysis.As the default JsonLoader function can not load the data so I search in google for some library which can load this kind of data.I found this [link](https://acadgild.com/blog/sentiment-analysis-on-tweets-using-afinn-dictionary/) and follow there instruction.

Here are the result

```
REGISTER '/home/hduser/Downloads/json-simple-1.1.1.jar';

2016-02-22 20:54:46,539 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
```

same for other tow command.

Now when I try to load my data using this command

```
load_tweets = LOAD '/TwitterData/' USING com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader('-nestedLoad') AS myMap;
```

It's shows me this error

```
2016-02-22 20:58:01,639 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1070: Could not resolve com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
Details at logfile: /home/hduser/pig-0.15.0/pig_1456153061619.log
```

so how to solve it and load properly?

Note:My data is about recent release movie deadpool twitter data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register below jar in pig, this jar contains the appropriate class which you are trying to access.

elephant-bird-pig-4.1.jar

**EDITED**: For proper steps.

```
REGISTER '/home/hdfs/json-simple-1.1.jar';

REGISTER '/home/hdfs/elephant-bird-hadoop-compat-4.1.jar';

REGISTER '/home/hdfs/elephant-bird-pig-4.1.jar';

load_tweets = LOAD '/user/hdfs/twittes.txt' USING com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader('-nestedLoad') AS myMap;

dump load_tweets;
```

I used above steps on my local cluster and its working fine, so you need to add these jars before running your load.

Comment: I mention that i register this instruction is  REGISTER '/home/hduser/Downloads/elephant-bird-pig-4.1.jar';    and the output is 2016-02-22 22:06:43,318 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2016-02-22 22:06:43,319 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - io.bytes.per.checksum is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.bytes-per-checksum

Comment: These are just INFO messages, did you executed your pig load after adding that jar? if yes then what was the output after executing the load command?

Comment: ok, then probably your "load" command executed successfully, you can check it by using "dump load_tweets"  command and see the output?.

Comment: **dump load_tweets;** and the output is 2016-02-22 23:34:19,500 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1003: Unable to find an operator for alias load_tweets
Details at logfile: /home/hduser/pig-0.15.0/pig_1456162429420.log

Comment: where I expect some data

Comment: I just updated my previous answer with more info, please check and execute same steps and let me know if you still face any issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Register 3 Jar files as shown in the blog. Each jar has its own importance.

elephant-bird-hadoop-compat-4.1.jar-Utilities for dealing with Hadoop incompatibilities between 1.x and 2.x.

elephant-bird-pig-4.1.jar--Json loader for pig, it loads each Json record into Pig.

json-simple-1.1.1.jar--One of the Json Parser available in Java

After Registering the Jars, you can load the tweets by the following pig script.

```
load_tweets = LOAD '/user/flume/tweets/' USING com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader('-nestedLoad') AS myMap;
```

After loading the tweets, you can see them by dumping it

```
dump load_tweets
```